# Add RoutedEvent Handler on property change of class

Tags: c#, wpf, eventhandler, routed-events

I have a custom UserControl in a dll that I am referencing in my WPF project. One of the properties of this UserControl is `SelectedCustomer` as a string. Here is a sample of the code for the UserControl:

```
public partial class CustomerSelect
{
    public string ImageCollectionFolder { get; set; }
    public List<string> AllCustomers { get; set; }
    public string SelectedCustomer { get; set; }

    public LinearGradientBrush BackgroundBrush { get; set; }

    public CustomerSelect()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
....
```

I am using this control in my WPF project and would like to check whether the selected customer has changed - if it has, I need to update some information elsewhere on the form. Here is a sample of the xaml I have for the control:

```
        <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1">
            <CustomForms:CustomerSelect Name="CustomerSelection"
                                        Height="133" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                        ImageCollectionFolder="F:\Customers"
                                        BackgroundBrush="{StaticResource HorizontalGlow}" />
        </DockPanel>
```

I have had a look at the information Microsoft gives about adding RoutedEventHandlers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-create-a-custom-routed-event), but it doesn't seem to specify which property it is that changes to trigger the event handler and I got very bogged down trying to change things around.

How can I make an event handler to handle the event where the SelectedCustomer property of the control changes?

Comment: Just add it to UserControl, it's [not hard](https://www.wpftutorial.net/RoutedEvents.html). I'd start with normal event myself, why do you need routed event?

Comment: I can't answer your question - it seems there are whole swathes of information I need to learn. Perhaps starting with the difference between routed events and normal events. Maybe I'm not ready to take on this project yet, I am really getting myself so confused and bogged down trying to get this right. None of the examples seem relevant to my case, which is probably another symptom of a lack of knowledge.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do when the SelectedCustomer property is set? Can't you do this from the setter of the property?

Comment: Can you change that `SelectCustomer` user control's code after all?

Comment: @dymanoid I possibly could change tho user control's code, but I think I am more likely to misunderstand and break it than anything else - I'd rather deal with what it provides if possible.

Comment: @mm8 I may be able to do it from the Setter if the Setter is capable of being told which property of the control to look at... I have other controls in the form that need to be updated when the SelectedCustomer property is set - for instance, there might be a textblock with the customer's address displayed and so on. I can look up this data from the customer that is selected.

Comment: So define an event and raise it whenever the property is being set to a new value?

Comment: Of Course! I reckon that will do it - I remember seeing something like that in one of the training videos;